# Manual synchronization SQL Server enigma

Tags: sql-server-2008, merge-replication, data-synchronization

I've installed two SQL Server 2008 in two sites linked by internet connection and I've installed a merge replication between them, but one of the sites got a long disconnection time and the customer asked us for a manual synchronization (file-based) so they can make servers synchronized in this situation.

My simple question is :
What's the best tool to generate changes from both databases and apply the result to both databases ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can connect to both databases, you can use the tablediff utility.

Comment: Can I get the same result as merge replication ? in the case I add some new rows in target database's tables and excute tablediff, it will generate a delete statement for these rows because they don't exist in a source database.

Comment: the tablediff will generate insert/update/delete statements to bring a target up to date with the source. you can configure which one you want to be the source or the target. i suggest you check out the documentation and play around with it.

Comment: I think I couldn't get understood, even in microsoft forum, they suggested me to use tabldiff but it doesn't work as I expected.

ex: I have DB1.table1 and DB2.table1 if I insert different rows in each DB1 and DB2 tables and excute tabldiff from DB1.table1 to DB2.table2, it will generate a delete statement to all inserted rows in the target table because they don't exist on the source table that what I'm trying to avoid !